# References in VB.net and Basic Programming

Tags: vb.net, reference

I have been programming for some time, but I have some fundamental questions, one of them is as follows:

```
Public Class PriceListDetails
    Dim pricelist As BSPLib.PriceLists.PriceList
    Dim IsReadOnly1 As Boolean

    Public Sub New(ByVal IsReadonly2 As Boolean)

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

        'Readonly prevents from Modifying/Saving
        IsReadOnly1 = IsReadonly
    End Sub
End Class
```

Is it compulsory to create IsReadyOnly1 and IsReadyOnly2, is there a way to take the parameter from new method to IsReadyOnly1 Directly like in reference type?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to tell what you mean, the posted code cannot compile.  I'll suppose you mean this:

```
Private IsReadOnly As Boolean

Public Sub New(ByVal IsReadOnly As Boolean)
    InitializeComponent()
    Me.IsReadOnly = IsReadOnly
End Sub
```

Where the *Me* keyword ensures that the field is assigned instead of the parameter.

Comment: Thank you.  So, It is a must to initialize another variable at New()?

Comment: No, it is merely a very smart thing to do.  Because it you provide a default constructor then somebody is going to use it and forget to initialize the member.

Answer (score 2):

Setting members with constructor parameters is pretty much common practice in OOP.  However, if you are using public properties then you could use object initializers as well:

```
Dim priceList1 = New PriceListDetails With {.IsReadOnly = True}
```

Comment: That helps a lot, but giving with a constructor is easy.

Answer (score 0):

Boolean is not reference type variable, so it's not possible.

In case you want to copy the reference,then also you need both variable. You can take only IsReadonly2 as reference.